# DatastoreNeedIndexException in GAE even after indexes are being served

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I am getting below error when deployed on GAE, However my application is working fine in local server.

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
    <datastore-index kind="Order" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="employee" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="__key__" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="route" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>
```

Even when the Index I require are serving in GAE

```
__key__ ?                                           Serving     6202    1 MByte
__key__ ? , route ?                                 Serving     6202    1 MByte
__key__ ? , route ? , __key__ ?                     Serving     6202    2 MBytes
customerName ? , __key__ ?                          Serving     6202    1 MByte
customerName ? , employee ? , oDate ? , __key__ ?   Serving     6202    2 MBytes
customerName ? , oDate ? , __key__ ?                Serving     6202    1 MByte
employee ? , __key__ ? , route ?                    Serving     6202    1 MByte
employee ? , __key__ ?                              Serving     6202    1 MByte
employee ? , oDate ? , __key__ ?                    Serving     6202    1 MByte
oDate ? , __key__ ?                                 Serving     6202    1 MByte
route ? , __key__ ?                                 Serving     6202    1 MByte
```

And also the contents of datastore-indexes.xml are updated as per the error suggestion

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
    <!-- Used 7 times in query history -->
    <datastore-index kind="Order" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="employee" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="__key__" direction="asc"/>
        <property name="route" direction="asc"/>
    </datastore-index>

    <!-- Used 16 times in query history -->
    <datastore-index kind="LineItem" ancestor="false" source="manual">
        <property name="itemName" direction="asc" />
        <property name="orderID" direction="asc" />
        <property name="quantity" direction="asc" />
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

And this is the query I am trying to run.

```
Filter employeeFilter = new FilterPredicate("employee",FilterOperator.EQUAL, saleRepID);
Filter startTimeFilter = new FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY,FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, startOrderKey);
Filter endTimeFilter = new FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY,FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, endOrderKey);

logger.warning("Creating a Final filter to find a uniquely visited routes by that employee in that particular time range");
Filter finalFilterForRoutes = CompositeFilterOperator.and(endTimeFilter, CompositeFilterOperator.and(employeeFilter,startTimeFilter));

logger.warning("Finding a uniquely visited routes by that employee on that particular day");
    QueryResultList<Entity> allRoutesVisited = datastore.prepare(new Query("Order").addProjection(
                                    new PropertyProjection("route",String.class)).setDistinct(true)
                                    .setFilter(finalFilterForRoutes))
                                    .asQueryResultList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are hitting a bug in the validation code (which has already fixed and should be out in either 1.8.5 or 1.8.6). That query is actually not supported because it requires both '__key__' and 'route' to be the first value in the sort order of the index (which is impossible). If you want to executed this query, you will have to gather the distinct values of 'route' in memory.